# deleting a specific set of characters in a php string

Tags: php, string, url, strpos

Below I've got a tiny bit of all my coding, this is the thing I need. $linkurl is just a regular url. 
I want this code so the possible `http://` or `https://` won't be in the link before i put it in my database. It's a fault prevention for when people add `http://` themselves so you can't get urls with `http://http://` in the database.

```
if (strpos($linkurl,'http://') !== false){
    $linkurl-http://=$linkurl
}
```

The problem is, I don't know what to type in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `http://` and `https://` with this sinppet of code, using regular expressions.

```
$linkurl = 'http://example.com'; //Works for https too
$replaced = preg_replace('@(http://|https://)@i', '',  $linkurl);
echo $replaced;
```

Comment: Can simplify the regex to `/^(https?:\/\/)` (which is PHP equivalent of `^https?://`)

Comment: Yes, that is the same. In my example I've used `@` as delimiter, because in that case I do not need to escape the `/` characters, and in my case, I've checked both `http://` and `https://` too. What you presented is good for `https://` only, and there is a mussing `/` delimiter at the and.

Answer (score 0):

lolka_bolka answer is correct, however, you may also use a non-regex version:

```
$linkurl = 'http://example.com';
$toreplace = ['http://', 'https://']; // can add more things like ftp:// or whatever you like
$replaced = str_replace($toreplace, '', $linkurl);

echo $replaced;
```

If you use an old version of PHP you need to use `$toreplace = array('http://', 'https://');` instead

Comment: well indeed, that looks nicer, problem is that "['http://', 'https://'];" will give an error because of the [, ] and ,.

Comment: I have updated an the answer. But yes, this is 5.4 syntax and I'd highly recommend updating your PHP version.